# Restrict Server access

Tags: php, linux, web-services, ubuntu

I recently started running my own linux (Ubuntu) web server from home and have had no problems thus far. I am running the server through a home wireless router and the IP Address of the server is XXX.XXX.1.7

I have stored some files XXX.XXX.1.7/myFiles/Data and I can see all the files without having to FTP through fileZilla

When I run the server from outside my home network, I simply enter my IP Address as myIP#.XXX/myFiles/Data

Here is the problem, I don't want others to be able to access my server files from outside my home network without permission but I do want them to be able to access the website, just not myFiles... How can I make it ask for a password or perhaps block everyone seeing those files without proper permission?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you access your files without FTP? Do you have a samba share?

Comment: A: What web server do you use (Apache, Nginx, ...)? B: What did you already try? C: Have you tried googling *"<insert webserver name here> password protect directory"*?

Comment: @Atropo I simply enter my ip address into the browser (to view them or download if I wish). To actually modify or download again I use FTP

Comment: @helmbert Apache. I'm guessing you down voted me... I wasn't sure what to search because I am new to web/server development. I apologize if this question "annoyed" you but I would not have come here and explained all of that if I knew what to search. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your using Apache you can do it with `.htaccess`

Simple Google search I found a article how to do it. You can add multiple users and at a later time you don't wan't the person to have access you can remove their user and password.

http://www.htaccesstools.com/articles/password-protection/

Comment: Thank you I wasn't sure what to search. It was apache. I will accept

Answer (score -1):

think of to suphp an suexec module to apache after that create a user for your website dont forget to give him password :) (user for each website)

see google for instalation

and to deny access to your folder make password for your home dir